# facebook page to wordpress

Tags: wordpress, facebook

Maybe i mis something completely, but this site : http://www.tourisme-charlevoix.com/fr/ is having a facebook "iframe" style of the feed in there site.. a  of two lines

How do i build that from my facebook page for my wordpress site....

Comment: this is pretty close to what i need... but not perfect : http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/activity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just copy code they have and put on your site:

```
<fb:fan width="497" connections="" stream="1" profile_id="<PAGE_ID>"></fb:fan>
```

This fan box is now replaced by almost identical [like box](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like-box). If you set `connections=""` in element parameters it also shouldn't display those faces below.

In order to render this FBML you need to use [Facebook Javascript API](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.init) (not sure how that works in wordpress).

Also you can just get iframe code.

Answer (score 0):

Different plugins handle Facebook: [WordPress › Search for facebook Plugins](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/search.php?q=facebook&sort=)

Or the API for the Live Stream, which doesn't require a plugin. This shows how to get the iFrame code: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/live-stream

Comment: in the web site above... single line no plugin.... maybe it come from faceboon application... but cannot find it

Comment: You're right, no direct plugin. But the link to the API page at Facebook shows how to get the code for the iFrame.